# What does the phrase "the whole world was a vast, aching echo…" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases, phrase-meaning

We are currently reading a book about bats. The point of view is of a young bat named Shade, who got lost while migrating to hibernaculum. It is as of now winter, and they are attempting to discover two mountains shaped like wolf ears. The ground is canvassed in a thick layer of snow. Because of the solid breeze, it is extremely difficult for them to use echolocation.

My educator asked us to re-write the passage into our own words, while explaining what the author was trying to express.

I never used a website like this, so please be kind to me!

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Your title and description are completely different from each other. Furthermore, *proofreading/ rephrasing* is off-topic.

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul ah, I apologize. I never used this type of website before, so I am a bit flustered. Could you please explain how I am supposed to help others answer my question?

Comment: [Help centre](https://english.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: Perhaps you can try https://writing.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Gustavson Thank you! ヘ(^_^ヘ)

Comment: "The whole world is a vast echo" would be bad for a bat who uses echolocation, since, with no individualized echos, there would be no way to tell one place from another.